# Unable to connect to Hive using HiveOperator from Airflow 2.1.2 DAG

Tags: python, docker, hadoop, hive, airflow

I have been struggling to run Hive queries from the HiveOperator task. Hive and Airflow are installed in docker containers and I can query Hive tables from python code from the Airflow container and also via Hive CLI successfully. But when I run Airflow DAG, I see an error stating that the hive/beeline file is not found.

**DAG:**

```
dag_hive = DAG(dag_id = "hive_script",
          schedule_interval = '* * * * *',
            start_date = airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1))

hql_query = """
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.test_af(
`test` int);
insert into mydb.test_af values (1);
"""

hive_task = HiveOperator(hql = hql_query,
          task_id = "hive_script_task",
            hive_cli_conn_id = "hive_local",
              dag = dag_hive
              )

hive_task

if __name__ == '__main__ ':
      dag_hive.cli()
```

**Log:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1157, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1331, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1361, in _execute_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/hive/operators/hive.py", line 156, in execute
    self.hook.run_cli(hql=self.hql, schema=self.schema, hive_conf=self.hiveconfs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/hive/hooks/hive.py", line 249, in run_cli
    hive_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, cwd=tmp_dir, close_fds=True
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'beeline': 'beeline'
[2021-08-19 12:22:04,291] {taskinstance.py:1551} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=***_script, task_id=***_script_task, execution_date=20210819T122100, start_date=20210819T122204, end_date=20210819T122204
[2021-08-19 12:22:04,323] {local_task_job.py:149} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

It would be great if someone helps me.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install beeline in the Apache Airflow image. It depends on what Airflow image you are using, but the Airflow's "Reference" image contains only  most common providers and hive is not among them. You should extend or customise the image to add beeline to be available in your path in airflow image.

You can read more about extending/customising Airflow image at https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#adding-new-apt-package

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I have installed hive and Hadoop dependencies and set system variables for hive as well as beeline. Also, installed apache.hive providers using pip. I can connect directly using  `beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://ip.add:port' -n uname -p pwd` from the same Docker container. I have checked the user `whoami` from DAG and also in CLI both are the same users. So I am confused about what am I missing.

Comment: I am confused too. It should work if your custom image is build on the official image and follows the 'extend' or customise pattern. I think you need to elaborate on how you build your custom image, i am afraid beeline is not on the PATH for airflow user, can you elaborate on that ? Did you follow the build image guidelines from the community? (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html) or did you build in some other way totally custom?

Comment: I made a couple of changes to Dockerfile and now I'm able to connect to Hive.
Added
1. Hive location to PATH variable as you suggested. 
2. hive-site.xml
3. Jdk8
(I'm not sure why there were no problems when I am trying to connect via CIL from Airflow Container)
Thanks for the help @Jarek

Comment: @PavanKumarYerravelly could you please elaborate the changes you made to your Dockerfile and what you meant by "2. hive-site.xml"

Comment: @user9492428 I have downloaded and set up the same Hive version in the Airflow container and also copied the hive-site.xml file to have all the configurations.

Answer (score 0):

This is my Dockerfile based on the responses here and others. You need to download hadoop and hive libraries, unpack them and update my Dockerfile below for the correct versions. Download the "bin.tar.gz" files and not the "src.tar.gz" files. Download them from:

https://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html
https://hive.apache.org/general/downloads/

unpack them with `tar -xvzf <filename>`

Once you build the image and spin up airflow you should be able to connect to your hive instance. I had to add this in the "Extra" box, however that will depend on your hive installation: { "auth_mechanism": "CUSTOM" }

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.6.2

# Install OpenJDK-8
USER root

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk && \
  apt-get install -y ant && \
  apt-get clean;

#need to install these packages for the "pip install hive" to work below                 
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends g++
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libsasl2-dev libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit

USER airflow

# Setup JAVA_HOME -- useful for docker commandline
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/

#hadoop
COPY hadoop-3.3.6 /hadoop-3.3.6
ENV HADOOP_HOME=/hadoop-3.3.6

#hive
COPY apache-hive-3.1.3-bin /apache-hive-3.1.3-bin

#upgrade pip as we were getting errors running pip install
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org

RUN pip install "apache-airflow==${AIRFLOW_VERSION}" --no-cache-dir --progress-bar off apache-airflow-providers-apache-hive

#run this to confirm files we copied exist
RUN ls -l /

#run this to confirm env vars set correctly
RUN export

#confirm java works
RUN java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1

#confirm beeline works
RUN /apache-hive-3.1.3-bin/bin/beeline --version 2>&1
```